# doctrine 2 dql alias

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to get dql alias for entity which doctrine adds to entity field names when uses scalar hydration?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, could you please explain it more clearly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
// build your query and then call
$query->getTableAliasMap();
?>
```